# Show popup image after click <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

I want to show image after click "show" button.
My button is this:

```
<a onclick="postCardNumber(this)" href="#">Show</a>
```

The "postCardNumber" is send to the controller the card number (String), and the controller query mongodb for the card image, and then mongo and the controller retrieve the image to show.

The Function:

```
function postCardNumber(tr) {

    var CardNumber = $(tr).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html();

    $.post("/CreditCard/ShowImage", CardNumber, function(response){
        //show the response(its byte array image)
    });

}
```

My question is how to show the popup image after click on that `<a>` tag, and close it after click on anywhere on the screen ?
There is anyway without jquery?

[image]

Comment: why without  jquery or js?

Comment: Just question. ill be happy on any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this in the past this way, it has worked very well for me because it keeps things very simple. You basically build your app in two (or more) "layers". That second layer acts as a global disabler; it can be used to turn off all interaction with the entire app, AND it can be used to place popups on. So you turn that layer on, throw the popup on it, if the user clicks the popup, business as usual. If the user clicks anywhere else on the popup layer, you tear it all down.

In this (extremely naive) sample, you click the blue box, it unhides the popup layer and puts a popup on it. Click the popup, you'll see the trace in the console. Click anywhere else, it all goes away. If you want, when the popup is clicked, you can apply the tear down logic as well.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maincontent">
             <div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; color: white" onclick="onBlueDivClick ( )">click me</div>
        </div>
        <div id="popups" onclick="onPopupBackgroundClicked ( )" style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>        

        <script>
            var popupLayer = document.querySelector ( "#popups" );
            var currentPopup;

          function onBlueDivClick ( ) {
            popupLayer.style.visibility = 'visible';

            currentPopup = document.createElement ( "div" );
            currentPopup.style.width = '200px';
            currentPopup.style.height = '200px';
            currentPopup.style [ 'background-color' ] = 'green';
            currentPopup.style.color = 'yellow';
            currentPopup.innerText = 'Click Popup';
            currentPopup.onclick = onPopupClick;

            popupLayer.appendChild ( currentPopup );
          }

          function onPopupClick ( event ) {
            console.log ( "clicked me" );
            // VERY important. Stops "click through" to background.
            event.stopPropagation ( );
          }

          function onPopupBackgroundClicked ( ) {
            if ( currentPopup ) {
                popupLayer.removeChild ( currentPopup );
                // if you don't do this, the element will be "gone" from view,
                // but it will not be undefined.
                currentPopup = undefined;
            }

            popupLayer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that you can add and remove that popup layer dynamically if you want, and the positioning of the popup basically boils down to a little arithmetic (if the clicked element is 500px down the page, and the current window size is 300, you would place the popup at y= 200). You don't have to compute X unless your app scrolls left and right. I've done this in every app I've written for years (if it needs popups) and it never fails. It is in fact in use in a Google application I was hired to build for them.